# How to show default message in extJS tagfield

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs6, tagfile

I want to place one default message just below to my tagfield.

My code : -

```
{
          xtype: 'tagfield',
          fieldLabel: 'Select a Show',
          store: shows,
          displayField: 'show',
          valueField: 'id',
          queryMode: 'local',
          filterPickList: true
    }
```

I want Some tag ex : "Hello" in that particular box

[image]

I was think to use a panel and inside two items 
like this,

```
{
    xtype : 'panel',
    items :[{
        xtype : 'tagfield',
    },{
        HTML : "mYtEXT"
    }]
}
```

but that is required lots OF CSS and too much work for play around.

Is There any other way by which I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `afterBodyEl` config in the tagfield.

```
afterBodyEl: 'This is description'
```

Comment: Thanks This is awesome.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can change the color.

Comment: The afterBodyEl will accept html. With that, you can inject style or class.

`afterBodyEl: '<div style="color: red;">This is description 1</dv>'`